# Can we load different images in differnt BannerRotators in page load under same category Banner in kentico

Tags: javascript, c#, kentico

I am developing on e Website using kentico cms tool .In that I have 5 banner rotators .i want to display different images in different banner rotators under same category banner in same page.

Comment: Do you mean different images on page load?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Different images in different  banner rotators

Comment: So are you using 5 banner different rotators? What is the logic on which you want to control it?

Comment: first I want to give default images to every rotator.based on that remaing images will be appear every page refersh.defalut functonality of banner rotor in kentico is getting radom banner from database in every page refresh

Comment: Maybe provide some more detail about your particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the banner rotator has a "Where" condition, you can pull in the banner categories in a where condition like this:

```
(
    -- If they share categories, then load only the banners with shared categories
     (
    Select count(*) from CMS_DocumentCategory where CMS_DocumentCategory.DocumentID = DocumentID and CategoryID in 
        (Select CategoryID from CMS_DocumentCategory where DocumentID = {% DocumentContext.DocumentID @%})
     ) > 0 and 
     DocumentID in (Select DocumentID from CMS_DocumentCategory where CategoryID in (Select CategoryID from CMS_DocumentCategory where DocumentID = {% DocumentContext.DocumentID @%})
)

    OR
    -- If there aren't any shared categories, then this whole statement resolves true
    (
    Select count(*) from CMS_DocumentCategory where CMS_DocumentCategory.DocumentID = DocumentID and CategoryID in 
        (Select CategoryID from CMS_DocumentCategory where DocumentID = {% DocumentContext.DocumentID @%})
    ) = 0
)
```

You may be able to use Macros instead to try to shorten this, but it will result in the same logic anyways.

Comment: by using above query i am geting data related same document category.it is ok.but i want to display that data in 5 banner rotators with different image in every page load.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways you can do this. Out of these two, the one using Client side would be much easier. However it will require you to make use of Browser's localstorage and store values in it and pass in it to Kentico macros through query string parameters.

You would use two webparts:-

1. Repeater - to display a defined banner image on the page
2. Random Document webpart - To show a random document which is not the document already shown during first load.

You would handle the visibility of both the webparts through Kentico macros.

1. During first page load you would store the DocumentID of the first banner image in the browsers's localstorage or a cookie.
2. On the subsequent page loads you would check if localstorage is set and would pass the value to the browser and use this value to hide and first repeater and pass the value to the Random document fetcher where clause.

Does this give you some idea how to proceed?

I wrote tan article some time back on how to configure Random document fetcher.  You may see this link 
http://www.bodhitreelabs.com/Blog/April/Displaying-related-documents-by-tags

Comment: there is default webpart banner rotators is there.can we get the output by doing any modifications in banner rotator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use item-index in your condition to display the banner images.

Answer (score 0):

Do this with some configuration on the page itself as well as using a Repeater webpart.

On the page type, add a new text field called `BannerCategory`.  Set the field control to a Category selector.  Assuming Category selector will not be in your list so you will have to go to the Form Controls application and search for `Category selector`.  When you find it, check the box for Page types in "show control in".  This will make it visible for Page type objects.

On the page template you want your banner rotater on add a Repeater webpart.  Set the path to wherever your banners are located (assuming they are all in a single directory and have categories assigned to them) i.e.: `/banners`.

Next set the Category to a macro (click the arrow to the left of the textbox).  The macro you want to enter is `{%BannerCategory%}` or whatever you named your field from above.  This will dynamically get the category name you have selected for the given page you are on.

Set the transformation and other needed display properties.  To get a random display on page load, set the OrderBy property to `NewID()`.  This will create a random GUID and order by that GUID.  You may have to also set the caching property to 0 in order for caching to be turned off so the random piece works as expected.  NOTE, if you use the Random document repeater, it will also cache so you will have to do the similar "hack" by setting the caching for the webpart to 0.

If you are looking for something else, you may have to specify more detail in your short description of the problem you're having.